# JavaFX 2 круглый ProgressBar

Tags: java, javafx, gui

Суть вопроса такова, нужно сделать круглый прогресс бар. Пробовал создать на основе ProgressIndicator, не выходит ничего нормального. Нужна помощь.

Вот примерно, то чего я хочу добиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужно создать собственный индикатор прогресса на основе классов Circle  (фон) и Arc (сам индикатор).

Comment: Можно еще посмотреть https://github.com/HanSolo/Medusa

Comment: Или https://github.com/torakiki/fx-progress-circle

Comment: Спасибо, Медуза помогла